# Set the value of a drop down list permanently

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Hello I have a drop down list :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlResultsSinceLast" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
   <asp:ListItem Text="15MIN" Value="15"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="30MIN" Value="30"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="1Hr" Value="1H"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

The default value is 15 . Now I change the value to 30 . 
When I reload the page, the value is again set to 15. Is there a way I can make sure that on page reload or when someone else logs on to the site they see 30 instead of the default value which is 15 .

I would like the change in the drop down list to be permanent. I would like to do the same with radio buttons.

Please let me know if there is a way to do this. I can think of storing these in the database and then reloading them when the page loads , but I would like to know if there is any simpler solution.

Comment: How permanent a solution are you looking for, and what browsers would you like to support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How permanent is permanent? If this is just for the session and the user submits at the end, using session variables is probably the best way to do this.  If you want this to be per user, you can optionally drop a cookie with the values (provided it's not sensitive information) though this has a potential to be wiped out at some point in time.  Otherwise a database with the information would be best.  If these are values to be changed and stored globally, caching is probably the best solution (though that would only be semi permanent)

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be global then it needs to come from some sort of storage (like a database or XML file)...if you want it to be on a per-user basis you can use session variables or cookies.

Answer (score 0):

To make the page controls permanent, you would need to store their values in a `database`.  Then, each time the page is loaded by a new user, the values will come from a **DB**.  On the first load, you could store these in the `application cache`, and then load from there instead of hitting the db again.

The application cache will be available to everyone, so this would be your best option to make it global.
Take a look at [using application cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18c1wd61.aspx).

If the settings change again by a user, then you would need to update the DB, and also update the cache.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it there, it is "hard coded" in the ASPX markup.  The only way to enforce this change is to data-bind the DropDownList to a data source that you have control over.  Like an XML file or a database table.  Once the DDL is bound to that data source, you'll always have control over which values are displayed.

Here's a tutorial you can use that shows how to do it via a Database:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/binding-dropdownlist-with-database-and-display-data-in-gridv/

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is.. add one more item to your list that is ---choose---- some thing like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlResultsSinceLast" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
   <asp:ListItem Text="15MIN" Value="15"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="30MIN" Value="30"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="1Hr" Value="1H"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="---Select---" Value="-1" selected="true"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Let the user choose what they want. Do not restrict as per your requirement because dropdowns and radio buttons are basically meant for options and you cannot user to choose a desired value. If you still need so, use a textbox.